# Plotting a Google Maps route in Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps

I'm trying to develop a system that will show the user a route that GoogleMaps has calculated. I can get the route, via the googlemaps API. The system will send the API locations which the user has inputted, so the points will be arbatary.

My current system for displaying the map is using goompy. This works by extracting tiles for a set location and then displaying them on a tkinter canvas. How do I also extract tiles for the route overlay?

If it's not possible using goompy, could you point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look at GooMPy on GitHub (https://github.com/simondlevy/GooMPy). The README.md contains the following text

> GooMPy provides a Python interface to the Google Static Maps API, automatically downloading and stitching together map tiles into a single image that you can zoom and pan dynamically in your Python program.

Please be advised that the stitching of static maps tiles is prohibited by the Google Maps API Terms of Service. Have a look at paragraph 10.5 (b) of Terms of Service, it reads

> ***No derivative works***. You will not modify or create a derivative work based on any Content unless expressly permitted to do so under these Terms. For example, the following are prohibited: (i) creating server-side modification of map tiles; (ii) **stitching multiple static map images together to display a map** that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation; or (iii) tracing or copying the copyrightable elements of Google’s maps or building outlines and creating a new work, such as a new mapping or navigation dataset.

You should use [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) or [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro) to draw routes and be compliant with Terms of Service.

Have also look at paragraph 10.1 (a) that reads

> ***No access to APIs or Content except through the Service.*** You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you **must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).**

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=es#10-license-restrictions

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't thought about the terms of service and I will do so in the future